# Grouping data hour-wise using Query Function in Google Sheets

Tags: sql, datetime, google-sheets, time, grouping

I have 2 columns in my google sheet - Time, and some Ids

[image]

My aim is to calculate the number of ids reported in an hour. For example, from this image we can tell from 10AM to 11AM - 4 ids, and from 11AM to 12PM - 5 ids. I want to come up with a **QUERY Function ONLY** that helps me do so, and group the number of IDs hour-wise. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: wWhat is the start time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A2:B, 
 "select hour(A),count(B) where B is not null group by hour(A)"), 
 "offset 1", )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Appreciate it really!

Comment: Hi, could you also help me with a query function to extract keywords from a URL? For example, https://play.google.com/store/search?q=messenger%20app&c=apps if we open this, we get "messenger app". I have normal formulas with which I can do this, but I'm constrained to using query function or Regex function only. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
=ArrayFormula({"Hour","Id's";UNIQUE(HOUR(A1:A18)),COUNTIF(IF(B:B="",,HOUR(A:A)),"="&UNIQUE(HOUR(A1:A18))&"")})
```

[image]

### Using Lambda

You need to set the range refrence once, like this example `A:B`.

```
=ArrayFormula(
      LAMBDA(r, LAMBDA(t,i,
              {"Hour","Id's";UNIQUE(t),COUNTIF(t,"="&UNIQUE(t))})
                      (HOUR(INDEX(r,,1)),INDEX(r,,2)))
            (QUERY({A:B}," where Col1 is not null ")))
```

[image]

**Explanatoin**

What we did is `Query` where Col1 non empty in the first `lambda` call and
in the second `lambda` we name col1 `t` for time with the call `HOUR(INDEX(r,,1))`
and col1 `i` for id's with the call `INDEX(r,,2)`
and we use the two columns in `COUNTIF` that can be **simplified** like this.

```
COUNTIF(t,"="&UNIQUE(t))
```

Now we join `UNIQUE(t)` and `COUNTIF` in an Array `{}`

```
{"Hour","Id's";UNIQUE(t),COUNTIF(t,"="&UNIQUE(t))}
```